# UICollectionView in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I think that sorry does not speak English well .

I want 4-way scroll. It was constructed as follows.

`RootCollection` View has vertical scroll.

`ChildCollection` View has horizontal scroll.

It looks working well. but it has problem.

And once on the first page , scroll to the right.

The vertical scroll twice .

Scroll has already gotta go to the right page .

[image]

I think `UICollectionview` has `ReusableCell` mechanism.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"mainCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.collectionView reloadData];


    [cell.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];

    return cell;
}
```

i recoded simulator
http://pass2phone.com/files/masse_test.mov

Comment: Your link for the recording is dead

Comment: If you are going to use the delegate methods in 1 class for both collectionView's, you'll have to have a check in your delegate methods for which collectionView you want to do something. Give them names or tags and do checks to perform code accordingly